# Wordpress Custom Post Type Index Pageination

Tags: php, wordpress, html, pagination, content-management-system

I have created a custom post type for my theme called 'Projects'. On my projects page i am currently displaying all the projects on the one page, using the following code.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'bw_projects', 'posts_per_page' => 18 );
                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    echo '<div class="project p-project" data-filter="">';
                    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID).'">';  
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    echo '</a>'; 
                    echo '</div>';

                    endwhile;

                ?>
```

I am using archive-projects.php which is using pagination much the same as posts. Code as follows..

```
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :

        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/contentp', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/contentp', 'none' );

    endif;
    ?>
    <nav>
        <ul class="pager">
            <li><?php next_posts_link( 'Previous' ); ?></li>
            <li><?php previous_posts_link( 'Next' ); ?></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

How do i go about creating a paginated projects home page instead of just displaying all available projects. Would i just add to my existing array (example 1) or is there a specific template i should be using for example (home-projects.php) ?

Comment: Why are you using your own query to begin with here? Wordpress’ archive functionality already builds the right query for your. Just use the `archiv.php` template as basis - create a copy, name it appropriately so that it gets used when the archive for your custom post type is displayed, and then adapt it accordingly to generate the output you want.

Comment: Yes i am using archive-projects.php template for archives. However as my www.website.co.uk/projects/ isnt looking for a archive template file it is looking for a page-template.php. This way i can also include page content from wp-admin. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as per the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination):

**Adding the "paged" parameter to a query**

If WP_Query is altering the main loop and the "paged" parameter is not set you'll need to add it with `get_query_var()`. This is so WordPress knows exactly what page it's on.

For example, if your query looks like this (without the "paged" parameter):

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3' ); ?>
```

you add the parameter like this:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>
```

The next example is exactly the same as above but with the parameters in an array:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'paged'          => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

So in your specific case it would be something like:

```
<?php
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'bw_projects', 'posts_per_page' => 18, 'paged' => $paged );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                echo '<div class="project p-project" data-filter="">';
                echo '<a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID).'">';  
                the_post_thumbnail();
                echo '</a>'; 
                echo '</div>';

                endwhile;

            ?>
```

After adding in your pagination, it's also likely a good idea to reset the loop, so as to return WP to the physical page(rather than your list of archives). You can do this with:

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Phill . That is working great, only element im missing is the actual links to previous and next pages. Shall i just include those as per my example at the top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Check below code for Pagination.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'bw_projects', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'New projects;' ); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Old projects;') ?>
</div>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else:  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'No results' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```